# how to get a minified JavaScript code from UglifyJS service using jquery.ajax()?

Tags: jquery

How to get a minified JavaScript code from [UglifyJS](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs/) service using jquery.ajax()?

[http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs/?js_code=alert(document.title)](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs/?js_code=alert%28document.title%29)

The only way (are there alternative ways?) I could get successful response from the service is by using: `$.ajax` with `dataType: "script"`, so it evaluates the script, but I'd like to get minified script as plain-text.

Any suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, since x-domain AJAX works by executing the code in a similar fasion to including a script tag:

```
<script src="http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs/?js_code=alert(document.title)"></script>
```

The only way you can get the minified version of the script contents is to create a proxy method on your local web server that your code can call using plain AJAX; the method only needs to forward the call to the UglifyJS service and return the string received back to the AJAX caller.

Comment: The web service at `marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs` has been discontinued since mid 2016.